# What's the easiest way to set up a LAMP stack?

Tags: software-installation, lamp

I set up a new VPS instance of Ubuntu and am wondering what the easiest way is to get up and running with a basic LAMP stack (i.e. which packages are required, which configuration options need to be tweaked, if any, etc.).

Answer (score 124, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

It will install all the basic LAMP stack for you, prompt for MySQL root password, etc.

More specifically it will install the following packages, and their dependencies.

```
mysql-client-core-5.1 libwrap0 apache2  
libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 tcpd  
libapache2-mod-php5 apache2.2-common  
apache2-utils php5-common  
libaprutil1-ldap libaprutil1  
php5-mysql mysql-server-core-5.1  
libdbi-perl libplrpc-perl mysql-server  
apache2.2-bin libdbd-mysql-perl  
libhtml-template-perl  
libnet-daemon-perl libapr1  
mysql-server-5.1 libmysqlclient16  
ssl-cert apache2-mpm-prefork  
mysql-common mysql-client-5.1
```

You might also want to take a peek at the [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/lamp-overview.html).

Comment: You might want to consider APT tasks rather than `tasksel` to do this. See this: [Should I use tasksel, tasks in APT or install regular metapackages?](http://askubuntu.com/q/252056/88802)

Comment: @andol how to install phpmyadmin with this

Comment: @andol `E: Package 'php5' has no installation candidate`,
`E: Package 'libapache2-mod-php5' has no installation candidate`,
`E: Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-auth-mysql` and 
`E: Package 'php5-mysql' has no installation candidate` How do I over come this?

Comment: The [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/lamp-overview.html) page returns a 404. Is there a valid URL for it?

Comment: @MikeWaters https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/lamp-applications :)

Answer (score 31):

**Install Apache**

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

**Install PHP**

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

As fo 16.04, the number is dropped:

```
sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php
```

**Install MySQL**

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

**Install phpMyAdmin**

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql phpmyadmin
```

As with the PHP installation, in 16.04, the number is dropped:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php-mysql phpmyadmin
```

**Combined installation**

16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php libapache2-mod-php mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php-mysql phpmyadmin
```

Before 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql phpmyadmin
```

Comment: Note: phpMyAdmin also requires packages php-gettext and php-mbstring

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/21762418/3160597 `libapache2-mod-auth-mysql` is no longer needed in 16.04

Answer (score 29):

The easiest way to install LAMP with PHPMyAdmin is using:

```
sudo apt-get  install lamp-server^ phpmyadmin
```

You don't even need to install taskel. More details can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131216125617/http://linuxtray.com/install-lamp-ubuntu/), which gives this:

To access PHPMyAdmin, open terminal & type:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Add this line somewhere in that file:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Finally restart Apache using:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

or

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I'd recommend APT Tasks too. Note that the caret (`^`) is not a typo in this answer. See also: [Should I use tasksel, tasks in APT or install regular metapackages?](http://askubuntu.com/q/252056/88802)

Comment: Whilst the usage of tasksel seems to be "easier", this should be the very easy way to do this task. This answer doesn't need other steps to do the job. Thank you!

Comment: Your link is dead. This is a good reason why we should always include a brief summary of what is in a link.

Answer (score 15):

In Synaptic, click edit and mark by task. Then select LAMP Server and hit apply. Done.

Comment: +1 for providing a slightly more GUI:ish solution, even if it's not necessarily available on a VPS.

Answer (score 11):

I personally always find that installing the MySQL server and then PHPMyAdmin will install all the parts I need

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

(doing this first means it asks for the root account password to be set in advance)

then

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

It also gives you all the tools you'll need to administrate your MySQL server once it's installed :)

Answer (score 10):

On commandline the simplest way is probably to use [tasksel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel):

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

Answer (score 4):

The packages are `apache2` and `libapache2-mod-php5`. php5 has a number of additional modules, you may need some. List them with `apt-cache search php5`

Try revising your search or

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5
```

Enable php5 with

```
sudo a2enmod php5
```

Restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

The following wiki pages can be very helpful if you are starting with apache.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/serverguide/C/httpd.html

Note- This answer was migrated from elsewhere. To add mysql install

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server php5-mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html

It has LAMP as well as phpmyadmin integrated along with perl modules. Installs in /opt/lampp so can be installed/removed easily...

Answer (score 2):

My Swiss Army knife command:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-server mysql-client libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5 php5-mysql libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt php5-curl php5-cli php5-gd phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP7.0 is standard on Ubuntu 16+

Heres the rundown:

## 1 As Always

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

## 2 Install Apache2

```
 sudo apt-get install apache2
```

## 3 Install mysql-server

```
 sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

## 4 Install PHP 7.0

```
 sudo apt-get install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext php7.0-json php-xml
 sudo a2enmod php7.0
```

## 5 Install phpmyadmin

```
 sudo apt-get install mcrypt
 sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Note, you'll need to add `Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` to the file you'll open with the following command. ([credit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55280/phpmyadmin-is-not-working-after-i-installed-it))

```
 sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

### Optional

```
 sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Type

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

This will install synaptic on your system

Type

```
sudo synaptic
```

to open it.

[image]

Go to search box

[image]

[image]

In the search field type **apache** and click on Search button

[image]

The following field appears

[image]

Scroll down to **Apache2** and select the box left to it.

[image]

Click on apply

[image]

Select all dependencies and follow on screen instructions to install.

In a similar way install

**php7.0** and **mysql-server** one by one

During installation of mysql-server system asks for **root** password. Provide it.

After everything is complete, close synaptic.

Now open your browser and in the address bar type **localhost** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

If the following page appears

[image]

then **Apache2** installation is successfull

In terminal type

```
apt install vim
cd /var/www/html
vim testphp.php
```

Press

<kbd>i</kbd>

Type

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Press

<kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Go to your browser and in the address bar type **localhost/testphp.php**

If the following page appears

[image]

Then php7.0 installation is successfull

Go to terminal and type

```
mysql --version
```

If you get the following prompt (version numbers for you system may be different):

```
mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.18, for Linux (x86_64) using EditLine wrapper
```

Then your mysql-server installation is successful.

Type

```
mysql -u root -p
```

You will get:

```
Enter password:
```

Give the password.

If you get the following prompt

[image]

Then you are now successfully able to login

Type

```
mysql> quit
```

to logout.

Congratulations, you now have a full working **LAMP Stack**

**Optional:**

You can also install **phpmyadmin** using synaptic. During installation it will ask for default server to use. Select **apache2**. Follow other on screen instructions.

Then open your browser and in the address bar type **localhost/phpmyadmin**

The following page appears

[image]

In the **username** field type **root** and in the **password** field type the password for root user you have selected during mysql-server installation.

Click on **Go** button.

The following page appears

[image]

Now you have successfully installed phpmyadmin on your system.

Answer (score 0):

You can install **Bitnami lampstack**.(Package containing all necessary sub packages of LAMP).

First of all create an account in [bitnami website](https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp) to download the **bitnami-lampstack-5.5.30-1-linux-x64-installer.run** file.
Then copy the file to your desktop (for convenience ). To provide read and exicution permission, Open terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T).
and type

```
chmod 755 chmod  755 'location of bitnami-lampstack-5.5.30-1-linux-x64-installer.run
```

Better drag and drop the .run file from your desktop after typing `chmod 755`, press enter.

Now double click on the .run file. It will guide you through the installation process.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a script for this task: [lampi](https://github.com/neurobin/lampi)

Usage:

```
sudo lampi -i -s -n example.com.local -dr ~/example-site
```

### What does it do:

1. Install the LAMP stack (`-i` flag)
2. Setup and configure *apache2*, *mysql*, *php*, *phpmyadmin*
3. Then set up a custom site named *example.com.local* (`-n` option)
4. Set *~/example-site* directory as it's document root (`-dr` option)
5. Enable SSL (https) for this site (`-s` flag)

Now, the site can be accessed with http://example.com.local or https://example.com.local

Comment: Unless you post the script here i can't see any use of this answer..

Comment: @heemayl : seriously? you want me to dump a ~350 line code here... If you are really interested, you should follow through the link and go to the github project page.

Comment: Can you guarantee that the script won't be removed in the future? Again its link only answer AFAICS. Also you should give the link to github directly, any subtle advertising is highly discouraged..Perhaps you should go through the related meta posts first..

Comment: @heemayl : I agree on giving a direct link to github but not on it being a link only answer. I have put the code that needs to be run and explained well enough to follow through for anyone...

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Ubuntu 16, it is simple with one command:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-server php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql phpmyadmin
```

And just follow the instruction on screen to enter password for mysql, phpmyadmin configuration

You can see more details on my blog   http://tvivu.com/install-lamp-stack-ubuntu-16-04/

Answer (score 0):

**Follow All Steps**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt install php7.0-cli
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
sudo phpenmod mbstring
sudo systemctl restart apache2
sudo apt-get update
```

(Note If phpmyadmin is not working after Than Try this last three line code)

```
gksu gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
sudo apt-get install gksu^C
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a made an easy to use, [**simple bash script**](https://gist.github.com/EmpireWorld/737fbb9f403d4dd66dee1364d866ba7e) that installs LAMP stack on your system automatically.

Just run this command in your terminal to use the bash script:

```bsh
wget --no-cache -O - https://gist.github.com/EmpireWorld/737fbb9f403d4dd66dee1364d866ba7e/raw/install-lamp.sh | bash
```

Also phpMyAdmin installation included in the gist.

[**Check out the Gist**](https://gist.github.com/EmpireWorld/737fbb9f403d4dd66dee1364d866ba7e)

Answer (score -7):

Try EHCP (easy hosting control panel) ...

ehcp installation on a clean server will do the dirty job for you ...