# How to setup LAMP environment?

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, lamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the easiest way to set up a LAMP stack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34/whats-the-easiest-way-to-set-up-a-lamp-stack)

I have been using XAMP in windows for a long time. Recently I have moved to Ubuntu and now want to have a similar environment to develop my PHP websites.

How can I setup the LAMP environment in Ubuntu? Should I have to install each and every app in that stack separately or is there a single package that contains all?