# lamp-server or XAMPP?

Tags: package-management, lamp, xampp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XAMPP vs. Native LAMP Packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56181/xampp-vs-native-lamp-packages)

Looked around for alternatives to WAMP, there seem to be two: lamp-server and XAMPP.

What's the difference between them? Anything in particular to consider before picking one over the other?

Thanks.

Comment: @hhlp: thank you, for some reason search didn't reveal this for me.

Answer (score 0):

personally I would install phpmyadmin, that will bring in apache and mysql and set it all up for you and give you a nice way to browse the mysql database. You can then put stuff in /var/www/ and it will just work. Look at http://localhost for your stuff and http://localhost/phpmyadmin for the database console. Do remove or secure phpmyadmin if you are putting this on the internet.

Comment: That's why I figured it would be better to just go with XAMPP because it has phpmyadmin bundled with it.

Answer (score 0):

LAMP is the most famous solution. Apache is present under 65% of web servers.
This is also the easiest and the most documented but not the most efficient. Nginx and Lighttpd are good alternatives.