# How do I install XAMPP?

Tags: 10.10, server

Can somebody please guide me to install xampp on Ubuntu 10.10 or simply to a tutorial that works. I've followed many tutorials from the web which unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: It might be simpler to just install PHP, MySQL, and Apache with `apt-get`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the easiest way to set up a LAMP stack?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34/whats-the-easiest-way-to-set-up-a-lamp-stack)

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 mysql-server libapache2-mod-php5
```