# How do I install Apache and PHP on 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, apache2, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the easiest way to set up a LAMP stack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34/whats-the-easiest-way-to-set-up-a-lamp-stack)

I would like to install Apache and PHP on my new machine, running Ubuntu 11.10, but I can't see either of them listed in the software centre. What do I need to do to install them? So far as I know, any version will do. I just need to find out how to install them in the way I am least likely to get wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for synaptic package manager in the Software Center and install it. Fire it up and then search for apache2 and php5-cli. Install both.
Also install libapache2-mod-php5 so you can execute php scripts on your apache server.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

LAMP `L`inux, `A`pache, `M`ySQL, `P`HP are external packages. Each package can be configured and installed separately. You may use the following steps to install manually.

Open your terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 mysql-server apache2
```

The above command will install latest version of PHP which is version 5 and mysql-server with apache http server 2.

You will be prompted in terminal to give a password for your MySQL "root" user

After the the installation finished check Apache is working. Open your favorite browser and type `localhost` in the address bar. You should see a message "It works!"

Also check if php is working or if not,

Open your terminal and type: `sudo gedit /var/www/info.php`

copy and past the following info text

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Save and exit.

Restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

open your browser and type:

```
localhost/info.php
```

and you will see the PHP info page.