# MAMP like tool for ubuntu

Tags: gui, apache2

I am from mac os x background. To control my apache, mysql, and php, I used to use MAMP tool available for mac os x.

On my ubuntu, I have installed all the required softwares but, I want a good UI tool to control my apache. To be specific, I change my document root too often, so I want a GUI tool to where I can just browse for desired document root, and restart the server.

Is there any such tool available?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The equivalent tool to MAMP for Linux/ Ubuntu is LAMP.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)

I believe this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 7):

MAMP is more than an installer. You can manage various aspects of your web dev environment, but probably the most commonly used is you can stand up a new site on your system with it's own domain name in seconds. It makes web development easy. So things that install Apache, PHP & MySQL only satisfy the least important aspect of what MAMP does.

Answer (score 3):

Basically inorder to use apache, mysql and php you need to install each component as they are all different programs for different purpose:

`sudo apt-get install php5 mysql-server php5-mysql apache libapache2-mod-php5`

and you need to start/stop mysql and apache as:

```
sudo service apache2 start/restart/stop
sudo service mysql start/restart/stop
```

I think mysql supports upstart as well so you can do:

```
sudo start/restart/stop mysql
```

Or you can install `tasksel` and install LAMP stack:

`sudo apt-get install tasksel`

and in terminal do:

`sudo tasksel` and choose LAMP Server which will install all required components for apache, mysql and php.

[image]

If you use unity you can use a quicklist for starting/stopping LAMP after installing: [What Custom Launchers and Unity Quicklists are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/what-custom-launchers-and-unity-quicklists-are-available/38436#38436)

OR

There is [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like XAMPP might be what you're looking for - http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

[source](https://askubuntu.com/a/45/113065)