# How to instal LAMP for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: mysql, tasksel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the easiest way to set up a LAMP stack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34/whats-the-easiest-way-to-set-up-a-lamp-stack)

I'm studying SQL database right now and I need a mySQL server. I was guided to use a LAMP server on Linux .. but I don't know how to install it on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS ?!!

I looked for previous situations like me and I found that I should install some software called tasksel .. but when I did .. something went wrong and it failed to install the LAMP server.

So, please I need your help in this problem

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/34/whats-the-easiest-way-to-set-up-a-lamp-stack