# Trying to install LAMP+PHPMyAdmin

Tags: installation, lamp, phpmyadmin

I am a total newbie and has seen lots of tutorials on the net but still can't solve my problems.

I installed LAMP+PHPMyAdmin the following way: sudo apt-get  install lamp-server^ phpmyadmin

Here are my issues:
1) I need to change my document root. I need to set it to /data/WWW. I tried the "ln" function, it creates a shortcut but when I access `http://localhost` it gives me 403 error. I believe there is some permissions issue but have no idea how to solve it. Please help!
2) Trying to access phpmyadmin via `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` does not work. How do I access it? Do I have to create some link to it?

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Maybe not a duplicate but [this is the best Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/q/34/12864) to follow.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the default document root in

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

Apache is mostly configure files. by changing settings in the .conf, you can achieve almost anything.

open a terminal and type:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default*
```

your file should start like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
```

change Document root to wherever you want, and press Crtl+X to save and exit.

then reload apache with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I following article I write about moving your document root to your home directory. The same procedure applies when moving it anywhere else:

http://www.techytalk.info/ubuntu-netbeans-lamp-with-xdebug-nonroot/

The only thing you should watch out for is to make sure new document root is writable by www-data user from www-data group.

Comment: The chown and chmod commands worked like a charm!
How can I access the phpmyadmin now?