# How to install XAMPP 1.8.2.0 installer.run doesn't start

Tags: software-installation, xampp

How can I install the new XAMPP? I tried out various tutorials, but it still does not work. If I type in `./xampp-linux-1.8.2-0-installer.run` nothing happens (it shows me `root@ubuntu:/home/pc/Downloads#`). Please help me.

Comment: Using root is not recommended... Could you also clarify what tutorials have you tried?

Comment: Any reason to run XAMPP instead of just LAMP? You're not on Windows/Mac, you see? [What's the easiest way to set up a LAMP stack?](http://askubuntu.com/q/34/88802)

Answer (score 5):

To install xampp 1.8.2.0, download the Latest version of xampp 1.8.2 from the apache friends or sourceforge.  Once downloaded, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, browse to the directory where the file was downloaded, and run the command(s) below:

```
sudo chmod 755 xampp-linux-1.8.2.0-installer.run
sudo ./xampp-linux-1.8.2.0-installer.run
```

(This will extract all the packages to the /opt/lampp directory)

Then you need to go ahead, and start the service, and see if it works

```
/opt/lampp/lampp start

http://localhost
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

<sup>Source:[How To Install XAMPP 1.8.2 On Ubuntu](http://dcageek.blogspot.com/2013/07/how-to-install-xampp-182-on-ubuntu.html)</sup>

Comment: Well, thats exactly what i did before. However, my mistake was that I have to use the 64bit version... It works now, but the next problem is that I can't copy any files in the lampp/htdocs dir. How does it works? Sry, for so many questions, but I'm new to linux.

Comment: @ClintEasthood, Try [this link](http://superuser.com/questions/268987/cant-create-any-folder-in-htdocs-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your guidance is more concise and frankly better.

Answer (score 1):

It's most possible that you're not using the correct installation file for your either 32 or 64 bit operating system. I had the same problem and it's solved as I used 64 bit installation file for my 64 bit Ubuntu.

Then these should work:

```
sudo chmod +x xampp-linux-1.8.2.0-installer.run

sudo ./xampp-linux-1.8.2.0-installer.run
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I can't add any comments, I am going to add this as an answer:

In order to copy files in the `htdocs` directory, there are 2 ways:

1. To work and develop only under `root` privilegies. Just run `gksudo nautilus` (or `sudo nautilus`) in **Terminal** to start the file manager Nautilus with `root` privilegies. (if you are using the default **Ubuntu** distro from Canonical). Now you can add any files to the `htdocs` directory. But this way you should be careful, because you can harm your system, if you delete some files or folders by a mistake.
2. To own the permissions of the directory `htdocs` to your user account (because `htdocs` is in the `/opt` directory, which is owned by the `root` by default). Open **Terminal** and run the following command:

   ```
   sudo chown -R yourusername:yourusername /opt/lampp/htdocs/
   ```

If you choose the second way, use this only for development, not for production. This is a hint for the XAMPP stack in general.

And one more hint for all novice users, who want to use XAMPP on Linux. Do not read any tutorials in the internet, because everything is explained very well on **Apache Friends** official web site: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html#377

Answer (score 0):

many time your xampp downloaded file in hard disk another partion (FAT32) that is same issue then this "xampp*-version.run" file paste in user/home or any directory

hp@hp-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-7.3.5-1-installer.run 
hp@hp-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo ./xampp-*