# Yum install fails on Ubuntu EC2 instance

Tags: server, apache2, amazon-ec2, yum

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.3 on an AWS EC2 instance. This is my first time with an EC2 so it's all new to me. I'm also not the most experienced Linux guy either, so I apologize if this is a stupid question.

I want to install a LAMP stack on my EC2 instance which I'm following [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html) tutorial. However, the very first step is to install Yum. I made sure to enable SSH, HTTP and HTTPS in my security groups.

First I typed

```
sudo yum update -y
```

It didn't like that and responded with "sudo: yum: command not found"

I then just did

```
yum update -y
```

It responded with"

```
The program 'yum' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:  apt-get install yum".
```

So after typing that to install yum I get the following messages

```
Err http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libnss3 amd64 3.14.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

  403  Forbidden
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libnss3 amd64 3.14.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nss/libnss3_3.14.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Considering this is the official tutorial through AWS, I'm not quite sure where to turn. I'd appreciate some advice/help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ubuntu is based on Debian, which uses [apt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool) not `yum` which is what Red Hat uses. The Debian equivalent of:

```
yum update -y
```

Would be:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

As for your results when running `apt-get install yum`

```
Err http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libnss3 amd64 3.14.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
403  Forbidden
```

Would seem to indicate you don't have access to that file (I get the same forbidden error myself).

`apt-get update` should resolve your 404 errors, which are probably just caused by an unsynced or outdated package index.

I'm not entirely sure how Amazon operates their EC2 servers, but you should be able to install a LAMP stack with`taskel` see: [What's the easiest way to set up a LAMP stack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34/whats-the-easiest-way-to-set-up-a-lamp-stack)

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. I was able to install LAMP with no problems

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the "forbidden" errors use:

```
sudo apt-get install yum
```

instead of `apt-get install yum`

Answer (score 0):

For me it was just because I was not running this command from the `/usr/bin` folder where `yum` is located. For some reason the `/usr/bin` was not in the path variable.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

I did mistake to run `yum` or `yum update` or `yum install git` to normal window command prompt.

**Solution**

To connect to `instance` to perform a quick update type in the instance terminal `sudo yum update -y`

To install git in your/my EC2 instance install *git* in the instance terminal `sudo yum install git -y`