# How to install Perl, PHP, MySQL and Ruby packages on Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

I need to work on [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl), [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL), and [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29) software on Ubuntu. Are these already installed on Ubuntu or do these packages need to be installed?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: you can install all of these packages via default repositories (open synaptik and search there) or try to find repositories with new versions or install from sources

Comment: See this question for the php, mysql (simply known as a LAMP server): http://askubuntu.com/questions/34/whats-the-easiest-way-to-set-up-a-lamp-stack

Answer (score 2):

To install PHP and MySQL on Ubuntu 12.04, follow my steps from this link:

[PHP MYSQL](http://www.linuxmental.com/settingup-lamp-server-ubuntu12-04)

Or use the following. Both are the same, and the above link was mine, and it will describe you everything.

Install Apache

```
# sudo apt-get update
# sudo apt-get install apache2
```

**Install MySQL**

```
# sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
```

Once you have installed MySQL, we should activate it with this command:

```
# sudo mysql_install_db
```

Finish up by running the MySQL set up script:

```
# sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

**Install PHP**

```
# sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt

# sudo service apache2 restart
```

---

**To Install Perl**

```
# sudo apt-get install perl
```

To find a Perl module that's provided as an Ubuntu package:

```
# apt-cache search perl <module-name>
```

Replace the module-name with which you wish to get install.

---

**To install Ruby:**

Ruby packages for Ubuntu

```
#sudo apt-get install python-software-properties

#sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
```

Press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

```
#sudo apt-get update
```

To install Ruby 1.9.3:

```
#sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.3
```