# Install PHP in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: apache2, php, software-installation, 14.04

I have ubuntu 14.04 LTS(32bit). I want to install php5.5. I installed apache server and I see default apache server index page on localhost correctly.
But, when I try to install php5 with `apt-get install php5`, I get error for unmet dependencies.

Also I try : `apt-get install lamp-server^` But I get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php5-json : Depends: phpapi-20121212+lfs
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the easiest way to set up a LAMP stack?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34/whats-the-easiest-way-to-set-up-a-lamp-stack)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

After installation invoke taskel from terminal

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

follow this link

http://www.unixmen.com/install-lamp-with-1-command-in-ubuntu-1010-maverick-meerkat/

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your terminal.
It's a great lamp stack setup wizard provided by tasksel.

```
sudo apt-get install taskel //then follow on screen instructions to install lamp stack
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use XAMPP for apache server and php.

you can download XAMPP from this site  https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html
and after downloading right click on the downloaded file and then click on the properties and then click on the tab called permissions then tick on Allow executing file as a program"
then open terminal navigate to the path where you have downloaded xampp then write the following command

sudo ./filename_which_you_have_downloaded thats it now install xampp through the window which has popped up