# What all do I need with my Apache Server

Tags: server, apache2, javascript

I was wondering what all extra I have to install on top of apache2.  My websites are running some javascript, css, and some jquery stuff.  Does apache come with everything necessary to run a website like this?  My searches have come back with little success so that is why I am turning my attention here.

Note*

cgi-bin is in the '/usr/lib/cgi-bin'

everything else is in '/var/www'  This includes index.html and the css, imgs, js directories.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is being used if anyone needs that information (No GUI)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Apache can serve files, and that is all that is necessary for javascript, css and jquery. All that technology works on the client side, i.e. in the browser. Cgi-bin is server-side technology, but that will work out-of-the-box as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Apache** alone is a webserver. The definition itself will explain that it can serve web requests to its clients as how the server is configured (HTTP via 80 / HTTPS via 443). If you're serving pages such as **HTML, CSS.. etc**, Apache alone should be able to handle without depending on other packages/services.

But remember, if you're serving **PHP, database, JSP... etc**. Well, you may need to consider on installing necessary packages such as PHP, MySQL, Tomcat... etc depending on your requirement.

Searching for more gave me [**What's the easiest way to set up a LAMP stack?**](https://askubuntu.com/a/45/179042) which is a simplified answer along with a link to its official documentation.

Hope this helps you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Apache has everything you need to run your web site.

Javascript runs on the client side. CSS is also interpreted by the web browser.

My suggestion is to not use cgi if you can. There are more modern and safer alternatives out there.