# cannot define phpversion

Tags: apache2, php, php7

I installed LAMP on my Ubuntu 14.04. Then , I want to upgrade my php version.

I checked my PHP version :

```
 php -v
PHP 7.0.5-3+donate.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
enter code here
```

Then I want to create one script file . 
I use this :

```
sudo nano /var/www/html/info.php
```

Infor.php:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

And I save it . after go to localhost/info, I see this:
[image]

How to solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the easiest way to set up a LAMP stack?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34/whats-the-easiest-way-to-set-up-a-lamp-stack)

Answer (score 0):

run `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0`