# Is Ubuntu Server required for LAMP server or will anything break if I install LAMP on Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: 14.04, server, lamp, webserver

I've already seen a similar question that was closed as a duplicate of this ([What's the easiest way to set up a LAMP stack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34/whats-the-easiest-way-to-set-up-a-lamp-stack)) However no where in that Q&A does it answer the question.

A little background: I have a 2007 laptop with dual core 2GHz CPU and 4 GB Ram. I want to repurpose as a web server and it already has Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Unity DE installed on it. I'm not terribly keen on installing Server Edition. Before someone says "it'll be too slow" my ISP limits uploads to 500 Kbps on my plan, even though downloads are 15 Mbps which suffices. Additionally I'll be the only person using the webserver (possibly NSA too) so speed isn't critical.

I know people will through in opinions on which is better and that is fine but I really just want to know if anything will break when I type:

```
sudo apt install lamp-server^
```

on my laptop.

Thanks!

Comment: When hosting a website, upload speed matters, not download speed.

Comment: @KazWolfe Yes I know... my point is under my cheap plan of only .5 Mbps or 500 Kbps of upload bandwidth the speed of the CPU and limited RAM on the 2007 Toshiba Satellite is the least of my worries. Doesn't matter I'll be accessing via cheapie phone plan with is GSM instead of LTE :D.

Comment: Maybe the question should be reworded to emphasise the *actual* question, which right now comes only at the very end.

Comment: @fkraiem You have sufficient reputation to change the title however you like. I won't complain but rather thank you for your good works :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Ubuntu Server is not needed.

You can very easily install all of the required packages for a LAMP server from Ubuntu Desktop. In fact, most web developers use this exact setup to test things!

As mentioned in the [question you linked](https://askubuntu.com/a/45/208574), you can install a LAMP stack with two commands:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

You may need to check some other things to make sure that there's nothing else bound on any ports, but (typically) there are no additional steps that are needed. If you want to access your server from the world, you need to set up port-forwarding and probably unblock port 80/443 in your firewall.

However, if you're running a LAMP server on your own system, it is ***highly recommended*** to run a firewall on your upstream router or your machine itself, as well as working through (at least, partially) the Ubuntu Wiki's [Security](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Security) guide. LAMP is not the most secure thing in the world. It's important to set up some best-practice topics to make sure your system stays safe, as well.

---

As mentioned in your question, you can also install the LAMP stack using:

```
sudo apt install lamp-server^
```

If you want to determine what packages will be installed/altered (just to be safe), you can run the above command with the `-s` flag to simulate what will happen to your system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't use a firewall... there's just an 4 port ethernet router with wifi plugged into the cable company. 3 ports are used, one to TV, one to Blu-Ray and one to this Laptop. The other laptop (potential webserver in question) will probably connect via WiFi to avoid cable clutter. I hope to have it crawl various websites (like AU) all day long while I'm at work gathering interesting nuggets and setting them up on rudimentary searchable web pages.

Comment: I'm hoping for double security levels (this may be a different question) At home via Wi-Fi all my devices should have "root privaledges" to change the webserver, but over the internet only "user privaledge" is allowed... ie viewing webpages on the webserver but not much else.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix That would be a different question. Using Apache, you can limit some functionality to only certain IP addresses, but, yes, that's something else entirely.

Comment: Well another good (separate) question would be if I should install Apache Open Office and remove my Libre Open Office. And should I remove LOO before LAMP install.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix There's no reason to remove or change your office solution for LAMP.

Comment: Thanks for your great insights.. I'll make sure not to comment again and only post new questions via new questions :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix to clarify, when Kaz Wolfe menitoned "Apache" they were talking about Apache httpd, which has nothing to do with Apache OpenOffice other than the fact that they share an umbrella organization.

Answer (score 0):

You can install LAMP on Ubuntu desktop. I was running LAMP and Moodle on top of Ubuntu 14.04 desktop. Worked fine.

Comment: Although not part of the question, thank you for throwing `Moodle` into the mix. I did a quick google on `Moodle` and it seems like a great app for those in the education field. Installation candidates along with LAMP to do useful things are always welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

From the terminal run `sudo tasksel` , choose LAMP server then validate with <kbd>OK</kbd>

> Is Ubuntu Server required for LAMP server or will anything break if I install LAMP on Ubuntu Desktop?

You don't need to install the Ubuntu server , If you want to install it run  `sudo tasksel` then scroll down and select  *Basic Ubuntu server*