# Finding correct php.ini file for lamp

Tags: server, apache2, php, lamp

I am stuck for 3 days. I used `locate php.ini` to find all php.ini files and its seem only one in my system, I also used `phpinfo` to locate and its points to same file.
when I run `php`, its show a its missing shared file for zend debugger extension.

```
Warning: PHP Startup: `Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/gmp.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/gmp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`
```

I have gone through the `php.ini` file

```
locate php.ini
/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini-pre1.7.2
```

I found no trace of string for debug extension. 
**How get rid of it**. I am also trying to add gmp extension .

```
php --ini
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/gmp.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/gmp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

after running `php --ini`

```
  Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/gmp.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/gmp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
    Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /opt/lampp/etc
    Loaded Configuration File:         /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
    Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
    Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Comment: How did you install your lamp stack? Any reason for why you didn't use `tasksel` or `apt` to install them?

Comment: you are using /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini . You need to look at the contents of that file for any references to debug extensions. You can also `locate gmp.so` and copy it to `/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/`

Comment: @Dan I downloaded the lampp suite and run the bundler

Comment: @bodhi.zazen `locate gmp.so` and copied to back to `/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/` **and I got this**  `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: gmp: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20151012
PHP    compiled with module API=20160303
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: gmp: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20151012
PHP    compiled with module API=20160303
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: @user746157 Sorry I'm not familiar with it, so I can't help much. This is not the answer you are looking for, but instead of installing it through a third party app, I would recommend installing and using the default packages from the Ubuntu repositories as they are heavily tested and stable. https://askubuntu.com/questions/34/whats-the-easiest-way-to-set-up-a-lamp-stack

Comment: What is the "lampp suite" and why did you install LAMP that way ? Normally you install with apt or apt-get. php is difficult to compile and if you are compiling from source or installing something outside the repositories you really need to provide us with such information. What options did you pass to php ?

Comment: Those php errors (module API errors) generally are because of conflicting versions of php or custom php.ini or related to your path. See https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/151 or google search the error message for similar discussion, but you have  not provided enough detail for us to debug

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Dan's question.

It appears you've somehow ended up with two different versions of PHP installed.

This is why Dan asked how you installed.

My suggestion is however you installed, deinstall PHP completely + start again, only using one installation tool. I'd suggest apt or apt-get only... till you get a working install.

You'll know you've successfully deleted all of PHP when /etc/php is completely empty.

You can refer to [Installing Apache-2.4.28 + PHP-5.6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964165/how-to-install-php5-6-when-using-apache2-4-28-complile-from-source-on-ubuntu-16/965418#965418) which I posted earlier today about how to install latest stable packages from the Launchpad PPA, which contains latest stable releases.

Since your referencing the **/opt/lampp**, this indicates you've attempting to use some custom installation tool or method, so you're mixing your custom install with the system install, which is doomed to instability.

This means you should also likely **rm -rf /opt/lampp** as part of your cleanup process + remove any related systemd files + any other non-apt cruft you've installed + remove any related, system wide, PATH settings.

Mixing install methods tends to either fail completely or randomly during various runtime operations.

Best to only use the normal system install methods, which will never reference **/opt/lampp** directories.

Comment: Hopefully link is working now.