# How to install PHP5.6 when using apache2.4.28 complile from source on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, server, apache2, php

I try to compile Apache 2.4.28 from source, I can't use command

```
apt-get install apache2
```

Because this command install Apache 2.4.18 only.

Here is my install step:

- Install dependency

  ```
  apt-get install build-essential 
  apt-get install libexpat1-dev
  apt-get install libpcre3-dev libssl-dev
  ```
- Download apache2.4.28

  ```
  cd /usr/local/src    
  wget http://mirrors.viethosting.com/apache//apr/apr-1.6.2.tar.gz 
  wget http://mirrors.viethosting.com/apache//apr/apr-util-1.6.0.tar.gz
  wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/httpd-2.4.28.tar.gz
  ```
- Compile apache 2.4.28

  ```
  tar xzvf apr-1.6.2.tar.gz
  tar xzvf apr-util-1.6.0.tar.gz
  tar xzvf httpd-2.4.28.tar.gz
  mv apr-1.6.2/ httpd-2.4.28/srclib/apr
  mv apr-util-1.6.0/ httpd-2.4.28/srclib/apr-util
  ./configure --prefix=/etc/apache2 --enable-mods-shared="reallyall" --enable-mpms-shared="all"
  ```

  [image: Configure result]

  ```
  make && make install
  ```

  [image]

  ```
  ln -s /etc/apache2/bin/apachectl /etc/init.d/apache
  update-rc.d apache defaults----> It has this warning "insserv: warning: script 'apache' missing LSB tags and overrides"

  service apache start
  ```

After performing the above steps, Apache 2.4.28 has been run. But I when I use

```
apache2 -v ----> it's not show the version of apache2
```

[image]

Then I install PHP5.6 like this:

```
apt-get install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt-get update
apt-get install php5.6
```

When I use this command it not only install php5.6 but also install apache2.4.18 and when I test PHP by:

```
echo "hello world"; ----> it not show any thing.
```

And

```
root@ubuntu:~# ps -aux | grep httpd
root        991  0.0  0.1  75268  3848 ?        Ss   02:47   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
```

@Edit: as the comment I change:

```
./configure --prefix=/etc/apache2 --enable-mods-shared="reallyall" --enable-mpms-shared="all"
```

to

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --enable-mods-shared="reallyall" --enable-mpms-shared="all"
```

Please help me, thank in advance.

Comment: Is apache on your path, run `which apache2` and lets see what you get!

Comment: It not return any things  :(

Comment: @George: I add some info to make my question clearly.

Comment: You installed it in `/etc/` and I don't think that the right place for a binary at least on Ubuntu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have done several things wrong. First this line:

```
./configure --prefix=/etc/apache2 --enable-mods-shared="reallyall" --enable-mpms-shared="all"
```

should have been:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2" --enable-mods-shared="reallyall" --enable-mpms-shared="all"
```

Your `--prefix` option during compile is wrong. I advice you remove it and fix that `--prefix` option

How to compile:

1. Download the source file for the version you want
2. Install build requirements:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential
   ```
3. Install `Zlib` for compresssion with these steps:

   ```
   cd /usr/local/src
   wget http://www.zlib.net/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz
   tar xvfz zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz
   cd zlib-1.2.8/
   ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
   make
   ```
4. Compile apache with these steps:

   - Move the downloaded `apache` source file into `/usr/local/src`, then

     ```
     cd /usr/local/src
     tar xvfz httpd-2.4.10.tar.gz
     cd httpd-2.4.10/            
     sudo ./configure
     ```

     - If you get `APR` error run :

       ```
       sudo apt install libapr1-dev libaprutil1-dev
       ```
   - If successful run:

     ```
     sudo make
     sudo make install
     ```
5. Check to see if it's working:

   ```
   sudo /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start
   ```

   - put `http://localhost` or your machine ip address and you should see a message saying "It works!"
6. Enable `boot startup`:

   ```
   sudo cp /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl /etc/init.d/apache2
   sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/apache2
   ```
7. Add to default `runlevels`:

   ```
   sudo /usr/sbin/update-rc.d -f apache2 defaults
   ```

Source:

http://www.linuxpathfinder.com/install-apache-from-source-on-ubuntu

Comment: let me try again

Comment: I am install ubuntu 16.04 again in vmware, i am waiting it done, ah, Have you tried to install PHP in your way?

Comment: I cant' do this command sudo make install in step 4

Comment: Ok one moment let me correct that, see update!

Comment: Ok do `sudo ./configure`

Comment: Please put this in your question so I can read it clearly!

Comment: If I do as my step and change "./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2" --enable-mods-shared="reallyall" --enable-mpms-shared="all" as your guide, it success. Now how to install php 5.6 to this apache?

Comment: Now, I not install apache to /etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66974/discussion-between-george-and-nistelrooy41001662).

Answer (score 1):

Ouch... Building Apache + PHP can be done + the build process can be painfully long + error prone.

Here's how I use the latest stable PPAs for installing latest Apache + also PHP which can be easily switched between 5.6 or 7.0 or 7.1 + soon 7.2, when it goes stable.

I do this in LXD containers, so machine (host level) contains only default code + LXD + no LAMP stack code.

Here's how I'd install latest stable LXD + Apache + MariaDB + PHP (5.6) + OpenSSL + HTTP2 + FPM (which is now required for running HTTP2) + Dovecot.

Steps I use to setup client hosting LXD container LAMP Stacks...

```
# Setup repositories, some of which require a bit of trickery

add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-lxc/lxd-stable < /dev/null
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php </dev/null
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2 </dev/null

add-apt-repository ppa:pdoes/dovecot </dev/null

apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xF1656F24C74CD1D8
echo "deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://nyc2.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mariadb-$(lsb_release -sc).list

apt-get update

# Install PHP-5.6 based LAMP

apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client libmysqlclient-dev

apt-get install php5.6-fpm  php5.6-cli php5.6-mbstring php5.6-zip \
                php5.6-mysql php5.6-curl php5.6-xml php5.6-xmlrpc \
                php5.6-gd php5.6-soap php5.6-gmp php5.6-pspell \
                php5.6-sqlite3 php5.6-tidy php5.6-xsl php5.6-bz2 \
                php5.6-tidy php5.6-bcmath php5.6-bz2 php5.6-dba 

a2enmod mpm_event proxy_fcgi setenvif alias cgid ssl http2 \
        expires headers include rewrite
a2enconf php5.6-fpm

# update PHP CLI, when multiple versions installed
update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6

# tune FPM pool + php.ini + opcache.ini + xdebug.ini + cold restart FPM
service service php5.6-fpm
```

Taking this approach will give you latest stable Apache + PHP + OpenSSL + as packaged code (no hand rolled builds).

You'll also get upstream bug fixes, as bugs are discovered.

If you hand roll your own, you'll have to constantly check many diff mailing lists to know when to rebuild + how to apply patches... which is another massively time consuming endeavor.

BTW, Apache-2.4.28 just released last week, so this Apache version will appear in the ondrej PPA as soon as it's packaged + code tested.

Likely sometime this week or next, so you'll end up with Apache-2.4.27 installed today.

Comment: You're welcome! BTW, Apache-2.4.29 has also released. When you're building from source, I suggest you setup Google Alerts to track all packages which change in your specific runtime stack. Then you'll know when you have to rebuild all your code.