# How to config new Apache path for PHP on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, apache2, php

I want to install Apache version 2.4.28 and PHP version 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04.

I installed successfully but they did not work together because when I install apache 2.4.28 I can't use:

```
apt-get install apache2----> this commmand just install apache 2.4.18.
```

Instead, I compile apache 2.4.28 from source as [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964165/how-to-install-php5-6-when-using-apache2-4-28-complile-from-source-on-ubuntu-16/964167?noredirect=1#comment1542715_964167).
[image]

Then I use apt-get to install PHP 5.6. Because default PHP for Ubuntu 16.04 is PHP7.0, I use this command to install PHP5.6:

```
apt-get install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt-get update
apt-get install php5.6
```

And it installed success!
[image]

So, when I test PHP:

```
<?php
    echo "Hello world";
?>
```

It show blank page, not print "Hello world".

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/local/apache2/conf# ps -aux | grep httpd
root      57261  0.0  0.1  75276  3844 ?        Ss   08:21   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
daemon    57262  0.0  0.2 364240  5760 ?        Sl   08:21   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
daemon    57263  0.0  0.2 364240  5760 ?        Sl   08:21   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
daemon    57264  0.0  0.3 429776  6100 ?        Sl   08:21   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
root      57647  0.0  0.0  21296   944 pts/17   S+   08:55   0:00 grep --color=auto httpd
```

I think it many something wrong in configure PHP path or apache path. But I don't know how to fix it.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to attach php as a module into Apache. See [this info](http://dan.drydog.com/apache2php.html)

Comment: Is the php module enabled in apache `sudo apachectl -M | grep -i php` ? Have you configured a `virtual host` and enabled it as well in apache ?

Comment: No, i don't know this. Please help me.