# How to run php on local computer?

Tags: php

This is driving me nuts because it seems like such a critical thing that I would expect there to be a lot of people asking, but I can't find a clear cur response to.

I want to follow along a simple php tutorial like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbZYRNgGAKE

I installed everything I need. Now what? How do I run a php file?

Comment: I really doubt if people are gonna watch a video to help. Can you post a specific error?

Comment: You can run it by `php /path/to/your/file.php` or with your browser if you have and configured apache on it.

Comment: Please check this : http://php.net/manual/pl/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: How do I run the file? Let's say I have a .php file. I can't figure out the command to run it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the easiest way to set up a LAMP stack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34/whats-the-easiest-way-to-set-up-a-lamp-stack)

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  You would get much better help if you would copy and paste text from your computer screen with what you have attempted, any output or error messages you are getting, as well as other details of what you expect.  I clicked on your link, but don't have seven minutes to run the video to try to figure out where you're going wrong.

Comment: @Melebius You don't need a LAMP stack to run php locally. You can run the php interpreter locally in interactive mode with `php -a` although that's an oversimplification, but I voted to leave this question open anyway.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz Thanks! The link you provided explains a much better way than setting up an entire LAMP stack or XAMPP like most sources suggest to do. If you submit that as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: It always bothers me to see a question with a pending accept voted answer reviewed as "unclear what you are asking" as this question has been reviewed by some of its reviewers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so here's the simple answer I would have loved to find but couldn't

1. `cd` into the directory the file is in
2. Run `php -S localhost:8000` (or replace 8000 with a different port)
3. Go to localhost:8000 in the browser