# How to get PHP lamp or mamp on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: php, 19.10

I recently changed my pc from windows to Ubuntu 19.10 I Love linux so much faster and simple than windows
but I want to learn php on this machine what's the best way to get MySQL php lamp or apache and all that good stuff for PHP development on this ubuntu machine?

everything seems outdated or there is always new stuff and new code hard to differinate what to use and keep up with.

are all the same steps for older ubuntu versions the same as on the new Ubuntu 19.10? any links or easy to follow steps on setting up my enviornment ?

Comment: One easy way: `sudo tasksel`. Enter your password. Use arrow keys (not mouse) down to 'Lamp Server'. Spacebar to select entry. Tab to <OK>. Hit <Enter>. Go get a sandwich while it installs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the easiest way to set up a LAMP stack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34/whats-the-easiest-way-to-set-up-a-lamp-stack) The Ubuntu versions don’t differ so much. You should try a solution for an older version (but use the nearest to your version if multiple differing guides are available) and if you get a problem, then ask.

Comment: @shire questions on AU get closed when they already have been asked before and have an answer. See the link from Melebius. It has all you need. Oh and MAMP is Mac only (hence the 1st M). Lamp (L for Linux) is our stack

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`

Also, you might find this useful: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-a-lamp-server-on-ubuntu-server-19-10/