# practice php on ubuntu laptop

Tags: server, apache2, php, laptop

I only have a laptop with ubuntu 20.04 installed.
I am anxious to learn php but the book I have only explains how to install php and set up local server for  Window and Mac users. I found a stack overflow page that explains how but it is 10 years old and I decided to ask this question.
So could you please explain how I can set up a local server and practice and test php programming?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the easiest way to set up a LAMP stack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34/whats-the-easiest-way-to-set-up-a-lamp-stack)

Answer (score 1):

There are three things you will need for this:

1. an Internet connection (to install software)
2. Apache
3. PHP

Here's how you can get a bare minimum installed and running on your system:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Update `apt`:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. Install Apache:

   ```
   sudo apt install apache2
   ```
3. Test Apache works by opening a browser and visiting http://127.0.0.1. You should see something that looks like this:
   [image: Apache Test Page]
4. Install PHP (and some common development libraries):

   ```
   sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-dev php-xml php-json php-mbstring
   ```
5. Restart Apache:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```
6. Create a test file in the Apache root directory:

   ```
   sudo nano /var/www/html/testing.php
   ```
7. Paste the following into the new file:

   ```
   <?php phpinfo(); ?>
   ```
8. Test PHP works by visiting http://127.0.0.1/testing.php in your browser. You should see something like this:
   [image: PHP Info]
   <sup>Your version number will likely be a bit different, as this was done on a 21.10 installation.</sup>
9. Start learning PHP

That's all there is to a *basic* setup with just Apache and PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [builtin webserver](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) from `php`:

Installation:

```
sudo apt install php-cli
```

Usage (From inside your test projects directory):

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

Then point your browser to [localhost:8000](http://localhost:8000).

It will automatically load the `index.php` file if there is any.
You can create it with any text editor and [start programing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php):

```php
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how can i stop the builtin server?

Comment: You can stop it with normal job control. So, if you started it in foreground, you can stop it with Ctrl + C.